# Mounting Fedora ISO DVD and then copy the full DVD structure locally

Tags: linux, bash, tar, fedora, mount

I need to recreate in a local folder called `/distro/fedora/` the full directory tree (including eventually hidden files, symlinks, etc.) contained in the `.iso` file just downloaded (`Fedora-15-i686-Live-Desktop.iso`).

I understand I can mount the ISO image using something like this:

```
mount -ro loop /path/to/image.iso /mnt
```

but then, which would be the best way to get a **copy exact** of what I see underneath `/mnt` in to `/distro/fedora` ?

`cp`, `tar`, `clobber`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 cp -a /mnt /distro/fedora
```

Or

```
 rsync -hxDPavilWH --stats --delete /mnt/ /distro/fedora/
```

The latter has the benefit of being efficient when updating, and it preserves hardlinked files (if iso9660 supports those...)